# How to set cookies in Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I have to scrap a site using Watir and Chrome browser. The site needs multiple location selectors to open. I need to set the location parameters in the cookie.

I have used the method listed in this URL:
http://watir.com/guides/cookies/

> On running the code I got the following error: Failed to set the
>   'cookie' property on 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:'
>   URLs. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoScriptResultError)

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://watir.com/guides/cookies/

Comment: @browser.cookies.add 'foo', 'bar', path: '/', expires: 10.days.from_now, secure: true,  I am using like this but its giving error

Comment: Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:'

Comment: Please add the relevant details to your question. And try to post a [mcve], not just a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
browser.cookies.add 'foo', 'bar', path: '/', expires: 10.days.from_now, secure: true
```

Reference: [Watir](http://watir.com/guides/cookies/)